# Empty value from element.getText()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this html code produced by Angular component:

```
    <div _ngcontent-xma-c13="" id="table-container" class="resizeable-container-ae64a343-d9ff-7fe0-be8e-c4b4134c0353" style="height: calc(75vh - 163px);">
   <mobileweb-mobile-grid _ngcontent-xma-c13="">
      <ag-grid-angular class="mobile-grid mobile-grid-top-gap">
         <div ref="eRootWrapper" class="ag-root-wrapper ag-layout-normal ag-ltr">
            <div class="ag-root-wrapper-body ag-layout-normal ag-focus-managed" ref="rootWrapperBody">
               <div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-top" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div>
               <!--AG-GRID-COMP-->
               <div class="ag-root ag-unselectable ag-layout-normal" role="grid" unselectable="on" ref="gridPanel" aria-rowcount="19" aria-colcount="3">
                  <!--AG-HEADER-ROOT-->
                  <div class="ag-header ag-focus-managed ag-pivot-off" role="presentation" ref="headerRoot" unselectable="on" style="height: 1px; min-height: 1px;">
                     <div class="ag-pinned-left-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedLeftHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;">
                        <div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ag-header-viewport" ref="eHeaderViewport" role="presentation">
                        <div class="ag-header-container" ref="eHeaderContainer" role="rowgroup" style="width: 427px; transform: translateX(0px);">
                           <div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; width: 427px;">
                              <div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="1" col-id="rowCheckbox" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;">
                                 <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
                                 <!--AG-CHECKBOX-->
                                 <div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                                    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                                    <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                                       <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-122-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
                                    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                                       <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Row Checkbox</span>
                                       <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="3" col-id="caption" style="width: 395px; left: 32px;">
                                 <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
                                 <!--AG-CHECKBOX-->
                                 <div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                                    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                                    <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                                       <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-125-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
                                    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                                       <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on"></span>
                                       <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                                       <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ag-pinned-right-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedRightHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 17px; max-width: 17px; min-width: 17px;">
                        <div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ag-floating-top" ref="eTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: scroll;">
                     <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eLeftTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
                     <div class="ag-floating-top-viewport" ref="eTopViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                        <div class="ag-floating-top-container" ref="eTopContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 427px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eRightTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
                     <div class="ag-floating-top-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eTopFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ag-body-viewport ag-layout-normal ag-row-no-animation" ref="eBodyViewport" role="presentation">
                     <div class="ag-pinned-left-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eLeftContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 900px;">
                        <div role="row" row-index="17" aria-rowindex="19" row-id="17" comp-id="178" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(850px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="16" aria-rowindex="18" row-id="16" comp-id="175" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(800px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="127" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="130" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="2" aria-rowindex="4" row-id="2" comp-id="133" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(100px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="3" aria-rowindex="5" row-id="3" comp-id="136" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(150px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="4" aria-rowindex="6" row-id="4" comp-id="139" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(200px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="5" aria-rowindex="7" row-id="5" comp-id="142" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(250px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="6" aria-rowindex="8" row-id="6" comp-id="145" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(300px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="7" aria-rowindex="9" row-id="7" comp-id="148" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(350px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="8" aria-rowindex="10" row-id="8" comp-id="151" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(400px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="9" aria-rowindex="11" row-id="9" comp-id="154" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(450px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="10" aria-rowindex="12" row-id="10" comp-id="157" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(500px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="11" aria-rowindex="13" row-id="11" comp-id="160" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(550px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="12" aria-rowindex="14" row-id="12" comp-id="163" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(600px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="13" aria-rowindex="15" row-id="13" comp-id="166" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(650px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="14" aria-rowindex="16" row-id="14" comp-id="169" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(700px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                        <div role="row" row-index="15" aria-rowindex="17" row-id="15" comp-id="172" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(750px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ag-center-cols-clipper" ref="eCenterColsClipper" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 900px;">
                        <div class="ag-center-cols-viewport" ref="eCenterViewport" role="presentation" style="height: calc(100% + 0px);">
                           <div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 427px; height: 900px;">
                              <div role="row" row-index="17" aria-rowindex="19" row-id="17" comp-id="178" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(850px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="179" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="180" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">coreytestb</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="16" aria-rowindex="18" row-id="16" comp-id="175" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(800px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="176" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="177" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">a</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="127" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="128" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="129" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Test</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="130" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="131" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="132" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Testing</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="2" aria-rowindex="4" row-id="2" comp-id="133" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(100px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="134" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="135" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;"> </div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="3" aria-rowindex="5" row-id="3" comp-id="136" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(150px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="137" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="138" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Middle of Pallet</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="4" aria-rowindex="6" row-id="4" comp-id="139" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(200px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="140" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="141" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;"> </div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="5" aria-rowindex="7" row-id="5" comp-id="142" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(250px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="143" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="144" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Front</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="6" aria-rowindex="8" row-id="6" comp-id="145" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(300px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="146" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
                                    <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-xma-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-xma-c15="" class="fas fa-check" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
                                 </div>
                                 <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="147" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Top</div>
                              </div>
                              <div role="row" row-index="7" aria-rowindex="9" row-id="7" comp-id="148" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(350px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">                                  
                              ................
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ag-pinned-right-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eRightContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 900px;">
                        ............
                    
                  <div class="ag-overlay ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true" ref="overlayWrapper">
                     <div class="ag-overlay-panel">
                        <div class="ag-overlay-wrapper ag-layout-normal ag-overlay-no-rows-wrapper" ref="eOverlayWrapper"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-bottom" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div>
            </div>
            ...........
            </div>
         </div>
      </ag-grid-angular>
   </mobileweb-mobile-grid>
</div>
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/6qmak66T

I want to get the text into `div` elements. I tried this:

```
    WebElement tableContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("table-container"));

    List<WebElement> list = tableContainer.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));


    // check for list elements and print all found elements
    if(!list.isEmpty())
    {
        for (WebElement element : list)
        {
            System.out.println("Found inner tag " + element.getTagName());
        }
    }
```

But I get only `mobileweb-mobile-grid` as a value. I want to get the value into this div:

`<div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="132" col-id="caption" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 395px; left: 32px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Testing</div>`

I want to get the value `Testing`.

When I run the code I get only `Found inner tag mobileweb-mobile-grid`

Do you know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your locator is incorrect, use :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);


List<WebElement> list =     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table-container\"]//div[@col-id=\"caption\"]")));
```

change:

```
  System.out.println("Found inner tag " + element.getTagName());
```

to

```
  System.out.println("Found inner tag " + element.getText());
```

or

```
 System.out.println("Found inner tag " + element.getAttribute("textContent"));
```

getText() retrieves  text which is displayed in screen only

Because getText or text() actually uses innerText ,and will not detect text from hidden elements .

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and
> HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are
> important differences:
>
> textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and
> elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.
>
> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText
> is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>
> Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the
> value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed
> styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be
> avoided when possible.)
>
> Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (version
> 11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and permanently
> destroys all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the
> nodes again into any other element or the same element after
> doing so

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Very strange. I get empty value `Found inner tag `

Comment: @PeterPenzov hi ithought you want to print Testing ? or you want the enitre html ? then you have to use outerHTML

Comment: you have to change it to element.tex()

Comment: I just want to get the value `Testing` The general idea is to get every value like `Testing` from the table

Comment: Then why are you printing getTagName , you should be using getText()

Comment: Texting is the innerText property

Comment: its not Not tagname

Comment: Very strange. I get this output  https://pastebin.com/ZQsNGqxX when I use element.getText()

Comment: element.getAttribute("textContent") use this see whats happening

Comment: may be that  element is not in viewport thats why getText() returns empty

Comment: Same result as https://pastebin.com/ZQsNGqxX I get with `element.getAttribute("textContent")` Maybe yes element is not in viewport. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: can you print element.getAttribute("outerHTML") and see if it is indeed the elemenet you are looking for ? elese its an issue with your locator

Comment: Your locator is incorrect i updated the answer

Comment: with outterHTML I get https://pastebin.com/heKNwMRQ

Comment: you are iterating through all child elements , only few child elements has text in it. You hsould retrieve only div element with col-id caption

Comment: Using `List<WebElement> list = tableContainer.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@col-id=\"caption\"]"));` I don't get any output. It's not finding anything.

Comment: Yes, the question is how to get only div elements with col-id caption?

Comment: Thats the locator use explicit wait

Comment: @PeterPenzov please see the updated answer

Comment: I get `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of any elements located by By.xpath: //*[@id="table-container"]\div[@col-id="caption"] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
`

Comment: Looks like some tag/element is not found.

Comment: you have to usee \\div not \div

Comment: sorry imeant //div , i updated the locator